# How to create URL link in search result using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have already created an search function in Codeigniter and its working properly. The search function shows exactly what I want but I want the result to be link to another page. I am new to Codeigniter. Can somebody please help me?

Here is my Model

```
public function search($searchterm)
{
    $sql = "SELECT title as title, author as author 
    FROM `edubooks` 
    WHERE title LIKE '$searchterm' OR author LIKE '$searchterm'";


    $q = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}



/******************Handler for search******************/
    public function searchterm_handler($searchterm)
    {
        if($searchterm)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('searchterm', $searchterm);
            return $searchterm;
        }
        elseif($this->session->userdata('searchterm'))
        {
            $searchterm = $this->session->userdata('searchterm');
            return $searchterm;
        }
        else
        {
            $searchterm ="";
            return $searchterm;
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public function search()
{
    $searchterm = $this->search_model->searchterm_handler($this->input->get_post('searchterm', TRUE));

    $data['results'] = $this->search_model->search($searchterm);
    $data['searchterm'] = $searchterm;
    $this->load->view('search',$data);

}
```

and my view

```
<h2>Library Search System</h2>
    <div id="formborder">
    <form action ="search" method="post" id="searchform" name="searchform">
    <b> Name of book : </b><input type="text" name="searchterm" id="searchterm" value="<?=$searchterm?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" id="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="tablebody">
    <table id="table" width="100%" = border>
        <?php if($results == false):?>
        <tr>
        <td>No records found.</td>
        </tr>
        <?php else:?>

                <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                </tr>
            <?php foreach($results as $r):?>
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><?php echo ($r->title); ?></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><?php echo ($r->author); ?></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endif;?>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
```

I just want the result to go another page.

Comment: `print_r($results);` in your view and check what is the result of it??

Comment: Should I replace the    print_r($results); with    foreach?

Comment: I just want to check what is the result of `print_r($results);` I mean value from database come to your view or not.

Comment: check have your query return data or not??

Comment: my query return a data

Comment: okk `print_r($data)` in your controller and paste the result of it!!

Comment: i believe what Saty is trying to ask is if you can provide a sample of how your $data result looks like in order for us to see what kind of result structure you are working with (i.e. objects, arrays, multidimensional arrays, etc...) . However, @Saty, being that he is using `$q->result()` we know that his `$data` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a link per each result to redirect you to another pge, you have to place that new page's URL in the `href` of your anchor tag, just like any 
HTML link. I realize you have a table, what I would do is create another column with a "learn more" link.

So in your case, change this:

```
<?php foreach($results as $r):?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="#"><?php echo ($r->title); ?></a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#"><?php echo ($r->author); ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

To this:

```
<?php foreach($results as $r):?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?= $r->title; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><= $r->author; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="<?= base_url()?>controller_name/controller_method/$r->id">Learn More</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

the anchor now looks like this:

```
<?= base_url()?>controller_name/controller_method/$r->id
```

which you would want to change to the method name of your choice, perhaps something like this:

```
<?= base_url()?>books/about/$r->id
                  ^     ^     ^
                  |     |     |
                  |     |    parameter
                  |    method
               controller
```

it will redirect to that specific controller method passing the id of your book as a parameter. your job now is to build that method so that you can retrieve that specific book by id and parse it to a view.

Comment: if I apply your code, is there any change need to be in my controller or model?

Comment: yes of course, you have to create a new method in your controller. do you understand that concept?